# NodeJS ExpressJS Restfull API

Tags: node.js, express, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to implement a webservices with nodejs and expressjs.

This is my code :

Node.JS and expressJS:

```
var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var skybiometry = require('./routes/skybiometry');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(require('stylus').middleware(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/skybiometry/facedetect', skybiometry.facedetect);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

skybiometry.js

```
exports.facedetect = function(req, res){
        res.json('{"used":12,"remaining":88,"limit":100,"reset_time":1395403077,"reset_time_text":"Fri, 21 March 2014 11:57:57 +0000"}');
};
```

When I call the webservices, i have this

```
{"0":"\"","1":"{","2":"\\","3":"\"","4":"u","5":"s","6":"e","7":"d","8":"\\","9":"\"","10":":","11":"1","12":"2","13":",","14":"\\","15":"\"","16":"r","17":"e","18":"m","19":"a","20":"i","21":"n","22":"i","23":"n","24":"g","25":"\\","26":"\"","27":":","28":"8","29":"8","30":",","31":"\\","32":"\"","33":"l","34":"i","35":"m","36":"i","37":"t","38":"\\","39":"\"","40":":","41":"1","42":"0","43":"0","44":",","45":"\\","46":"\"","47":"r","48":"e","49":"s","50":"e","51":"t","52":"_","53":"t","54":"i","55":"m","56":"e","57":"\\","58":"\"","59":":","60":"1","61":"3","62":"9","63":"5","64":"4","65":"0","66":"3","67":"0","68":"7","69":"7","70":",","71":"\\","72":"\"","73":"r","74":"e","75":"s","76":"e","77":"t","78":"_","79":"t","80":"i","81":"m","82":"e","83":"_","84":"t","85":"e","86":"x","87":"t","88":"\\","89":"\"","90":":","91":"\\","92":"\"","93":"F","94":"r","95":"i","96":",","97":" ","98":"2","99":"1","100":" ","101":"M","102":"a","103":"r","104":"c","105":"h","106":" ","107":"2","108":"0","109":"1","110":"4","111":" ","112":"1","113":"1","114":":","115":"5","116":"7","117":":","118":"5","119":"7","120":" ","121":"+","122":"0","123":"0","124":"0","125":"0","126":"\\","127":"\"","128":"}","129":"\""}
```

instead of :

```
{"used":12,"remaining":88,"limit":100,"reset_time":1395403077,"reset_time_text":"Fri, 21 March 2014 11:57:57 +0000"}
```

How should I modify my code ?

Is this a rest api in node.js ?

Thanks.

Comment: It works when i change res.body('...') to res.end('..'). But I don't understand why the json express don't work.

Comment: With res.json, you don't need to put your response in a string. Just send a javascript object.

Answer (score 0):

Try res.json with a JavaScript object. The framework will automatically create a JSON response:

```
res.json({
    used: 12,
    remaining: 88,
    limit: 100,
    reset_time: 1395403077,
    reset_time_text: "Fri, 21 March 2014 11:57:57 +0000"
});
```

Comment: Ok.Thanks. If in my webservices i'm calling another services wich send me a json -> The best way is to used res.end() ?

Comment: It would be the only way to output the string like you want it to be. In that case you may want to check though, if Express adds an appropriate header `application/json` to the request.

Answer (score 0):

Your string is basically just a JSON formatted text string. It isn't a JSON object yet.

To achieve this you need to parse your string as JSON which you do with [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

To do that with your code you can write it like this

```
exports.facedetect = function(req, res){
  var jsonCode = {
    "used":12,
    "remaining":88,
    "limit":100,
    "reset_time":1395403077,
    "reset_time_text":"Fri, 21 March 2014 11:57:57 +0000"
  }
  res.json(JSON.parse(jsonCode));
};
```